# Custom number pad on click sound implementation in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, custom-keyboard

I have custom number pad made with UICollectionView. I am getting pressed key value inside didSelectItemAt method. I want keypad sound whenever didSelectItemAt method gets called. And it should be dependent on user's device settings.

I have referred Apple developer docs but I am not able to implement it. Doc says:

> To enable a custom input or accessory view for input clicks, perform
>   the following two steps:
>   1. Adopt the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol in your input view class.
>   2. Implement the enableInputClicksWhenVisible delegate method to return true.

I tried following way:

1. Created CustomUICollectionView

```
class CustomUICollectionView: UICollectionView, UIInputViewAudioFeedback {
    var enableInputClicksWhenVisible: Bool {
        return true
     }
 }
```

2. Declared variable numberPad in a controller where i am showing number pad. And called playInputClick inside didSelectItemAt method.

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberPad: CustomUICollectionView!

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
 }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Show your attempt to implement the click.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call `playInputClick` from the view class that conforms to `UIInputViewAudioFeedback`.
2. The class that conforms to `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` and calls `playInputClick` needs to be the active `inputView` of a text field or text view.

Refactor your code to meet those requirements and the click will work.

Comment: Tried following code, its not working.
class CustomView: UIView, UIInputViewAudioFeedback {
    var enableInputClicksWhenVisible: Bool{
         UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
        return true
    }
}

Then inside controller 
textField.inputView = CustomView()

Comment: You can't call `UIDevice.current.playInputClick()` from inside `enableInputClicksWhenVisible`.

Comment: From where *UIDevice.current.playInputClick()* should be called?

Comment: It needs to be called when the click sounds needs to be made.